# CoreData saving is failing with error- Error Domain=NSSQLiteErrorDomain Code=101 "(null)" UserInfo={EncryptedStoreErrorMessage=unknown error}

Tags: ios, core-data

When I try to save data to core data it is getting failed and shows error as: `Error Domain=NSSQLiteErrorDomain Code=101 "(null)" UserInfo={EncryptedStoreErrorMessage=unknown error}`. Also I have logged it into firebase crashlytics and it is showing in the device configuration as RAM free: 0 B and Disk free: 0 B.
[image]

```
if (![context save:&error]) {
   // logging the error to firebase crashlytics
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code that saves and crashes? Could there be an accidental endless recursion and stack overflow?

Comment: This is not a crash, this is a log that we are saving into firebase when the coreData saving is failed.